# How to boot runlevel 3 as non-root user?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, runlevel

I'm using Arch Linux. I can boot to runlevel 3, but any other level than default (7) results in a prompt asking for my root password. (Including runlevel 3.) The normal login screen for linux is nowhere to be found. I cannot select a user. I cannot enter an account name. All I can enter is the root password.

Does anyone know why this is? Is this just Arch? Is it SystemD? I am PERFECTLY happy to find a distro that does not use systemd. I just need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. systemd does *not* cause booting into any default runlevel to go to arch's "rescue mode" runlevel
2. Using the old way of specifying runlevels causes arch to *default to* rescue mode
3. runlevel is now specified by a unit - the (new) proper way to get to multi-user is **not** to add ro/rw 3
4. Instead add `systemd-unit=multi-user.target`, to the end of the boot line

(5. still not super excited about systemd)